# Obtener registro, por cada cada numero separado por comas de un campo

Tags: sql, mysqli

Lo que busco es separar los registros, cuando encuentre valores separados por coma en el campo **ids**, para luego hacer un **COUNT()** limpio con el campo **ids**

```
CREATE TABLE version(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, ids TEXT);
INSERT INTO version(ids) VALUES ("1"), ("1, 2"), ("2, 3"), ("2, 3, 4");
SELECT * from version;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Script de BD](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=edfbaf8839412b3c7c547a2ec0187732)

Si un **id**, tiene varios números en el campos **ids**, obtener un registro por cada **ids**, a modo que el select me de así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El `idCats` que tipo de dato es?

Comment: Me refiero a la columna donde tienes o puedes tener varios id en el mismo renglón

Comment: Es una vista de otra tabla, no es una columna como tal, si puedo tener varios id

Comment: Deberías mostrar la tabla de donde salen esos datos, tal vez sería más sencillo obtener la info que deseas de ahí.

Comment: Disculpa el campo es tipo TEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT v.id, v2.id ids
  FROM version v
    INNER JOIN version v2
      ON find_in_set(v2.id, replace(v.ids,' ',''))
  ORDER BY v.id, v2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo, tome en cuenta que es una vista y almacenas varios id por cada renglón:

**ESTRUCTURA DE LA TABLA**

```
CREATE TABLE version(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ids TEXT
);
```

**DATOS DE LA TABLA**

```
INSERT INTO version(ids)
VALUES
("1"),
("2"),
("2, 3"), 
("2, 3, 4, 5"),
("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8");
```

**CONSULTA A LA TABLA**

```
SELECT id,
LENGTH(ids) - LENGTH( REPLACE (ids, ",", "")) + 1 AS Numeros
from version;
```

**RESULTADO DE LA CONSULTA**

```
id  Numeros
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   4
5   8
```

Use:

- `LENGTH` Para obtener la longitud de la cadena que contiene los ids
- Use `REPLACE` para reemplazar las apariciones de la coma por una cadena sin espacios
- Le sume 1 al resultado final

Comment: Como tu ponías el ejemplo, en ese caso quiero que el **id 5** debe de salir las 8 veces pero con el numero distinto

Comment: @José no entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: Ya modifiqué la pregunta, con tu ejemplo de la tabla será más sencillo darme entender